# Mostrar alert ou mensagem de erro em mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tenho um site, e nele tem o cadastro e quando o cadastro já existe ele mostra um alert dizendo isso (esse alert eu fiz em js, mas foi dentro do php), mas quando coloco a página pra ser mobile, o alert nao aparece, como coloco para aparecer ou mostrar uma mensagem de erro? (tudo isso pelo php)

O usuário vai colocar o cpf e email para fazer o cadastro, caso já tenha no bd, ele vai informar. Ta assim:

PÁGINA: processa.php

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0) {
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Alguém com esses dados já se cadastrou. Tente novamente.');window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
}
```

Mas eu queria eu o alert mostrasse pra o mobile também, só que não mostra.

Essa é a página de cadastro (só vou colocar o botao):

Página: cadastro.php

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar" disbled/ >
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
<span id="cpf"></span>Cadastrar</button>
```

Comment: Mostre o que você tem.

Comment: @thiago Pronto.

Comment: Eu no teu caso utilizaria http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ para fazer a requisição para a pagina `processa.php` e ela simplesmente teria como corpo o resultado da condição de `mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0` que seria `true` ou `false` e então você mostraria um alert caso o resultado da requisição fosse `true`. Isso funcionaria perfeitamente em desktop e mobile e seria agradável ao usuário uma vez que não haveria nenhum tipo de redirecionamento.

Answer (score 0):

No seu HTML:

```
<p id="erromsg" style="display:none"></p>
```

No PHP

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0) {
$msg = "Alguém com esses dados já se cadastrou. Tente novamente";
$out="<script type='text/javascript'>$('#erromsg').text( $msg ).show(); window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
echo $out;
}
```

Comment: essa parte: #erromsg").text( $msg ).show(); window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
ficou como comentario, não?

Comment: Tinha um erro nas apas, agora eu corrigi confere ai

Comment: A página php que eu coloco isso ficou toda em branca

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugiro usar um pequeno modal, como mostra a figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0) {
   $msg_alerta = '<span id="alertabox" style="display:block;position:fixed;width:200px;padding:5px 20px 20px;background:#ddd;border:1px solid #999;text-align:center;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);top:50%;left:50%;z-index:99999;">
   <h1>Aviso</h1>
   <p>Alguém com esses dados já se cadastrou. Tente novamente.</p>
   <input style="padding:5px 10px;" type="button" value="OK" onclick="$(\'#alertabox\').remove();window.location.href=\'cadastro.php\';" />
   </span>';
   echo $msg_alerta;
}
```

#### Alternativa (sem redirecionamento)

Insira o `span` logo após o botão <kbd>Cadastrar</kbd>:

```
<?php
<span style="display:none;" id="msg_alerta">Alguém com esses dados já se cadastrou. Tente novamente.</span>
?>
```

E use o código abaixo no PHP:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0) {
    $erro_cadastro = 
   echo '<script>window.onload=function(){document.getElementById("msg_alerta").style.display="block";}</script>';
}
```

#### Alternativa 2 (sem redirecionamento)

Insira o código abaixo após o botão <kbd>Cadastrar</kbd>:

```
<?php
if($erro_cadastro){
    echo '<span style="display:block;" id="msg_alerta">Alguém com esses dados já se cadastrou. Tente novamente.</span>';
}
?>
```

E no PHP:

```
<?php
$erro_cadastro = false;
if (mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0) {
   $erro_cadastro = true;
}
?>
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69858/discussion-between-dvd-and-nazare-lisboa).